# preg replace entire div or div content javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code(that i get from an ajax call) in a javascript string that i want to manipulate.
If the div coming already exists in the string, i want to remove it or want to change its content.

For example i have this code in a string:

```
<div id ="message_abc_support" class = "messageclass">
<div class="messageBlockImage2">
</div>
<div id="messageBlockText">
<div id="messagesname">abc</div>
<div id="messagesmsg">123</div></div></div>

<div id ="message_abcd_support" class = "messageclass">
<div class="messageBlockImage2">
</div>
<div id="messageBlockText">
<div id="messagesname">abcd</div>
<div id="messagesmsg">123</div></div></div>
```

now suppose i get from an ajax call:

```
<div id ="message_abcd_support" class = "messageclass">
<div class="messageBlockImage2">
</div>
<div id="messageBlockText">
<div id="messagesname">abcdef</div>
<div id="messagesmsg">123456</div></div></div>
```

how do i replace the other div with the same id? Please note i have this in a string so i cant just remove the div

Comment: Your title mentions preg_replace, which is a PHP function, but the rest of the question only mentions JS. Which are you trying to write in? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i meant the equivalent of preg replace in javascript.. till now i have just tried simple string manipulations. i run through each character in the string via a for loop and delete characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like my teacher who told us "Well, I've been teaching them Algebra for 30 years, I figured it's about time they started getting it".

To get to the point: Regular expressions are insufficient in strength to parse arbitrary HTML. There are a lot of edge cases and rules that cause bugs.

There are however ways to otherwise easily solve your problem:

The correct approach is to not have duplicate IDs to begin with. Seriously, there is almost never a good reason to have duplicate IDs. They are by definition unique. Simply do not add IDs to the divs in the first place. If you need to query for them consider for a minute what you're doing: You're querying your visual presentation for business information. Instead, use arrays and objects to represent your actual data and bind them to the presentation (with a closure or explicit mapping for example).

But... you already have this code.. And learning about proper UI structuring can take a lot of time.. And maybe you're not even the one creating this code on the backend.

So, you can use the built in DOM parsing abilities every browser has:

```
   var el = document.createElement("div"); // placeholder
   el.innerHTML = response; // feed your AJAX response there
   var elms = el.querySelectorAll("[id]"); // select every element with an ID attribute
   for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
       // check if element with the same ID exists in the document
       if(document.querySelector(elms[i].id)){
           // wipe the ID out, in your code you can do whatever with it
           elms[i].id = "";
       }
   }
```

Comment: hi.. so by doing elms[i].id = ""... does the whole div with the id becomes empty?

Comment: No, it just removes the duplicate ID and adds a div with no ID

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the elements of your page in a  `<div id="target"></div>` . and each time you get a positive response from the ajax call, just replace the existing content of  div with id `target` within your success block of your ajax call like this

```
 success:function(data) {
      $('#div').html(data); // as simple as that 
 }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply jquery selectors to the string and replace the existing content:

```
var s = '<div id="message_abcd_support" class = "messageclass"><div class="messageBlockImage2"></div><div id="messageBlockText"><div id="messagesname">abcdef</div><div id="messagesmsg">123456</div></div></div>';

f = $(s).filter("#message_abcd_support");
$("#message_abcd_support").replaceWith(f);
```